# How to code sign an app on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, code-signing-certificate, osx-gatekeeper

I have created an app in python on mac osx 10.9. Then converted it into a .pkg file.
But while installing, I am facing gatekeeper issue of **myapp.pkg can't be opened because it is from unidentified developer**.
So, what are the steps to code sign it to avoid installation issue.

MYAPP.pkg and when double clicked, this pkg file will install MYAPP folder in /Applications location.
This MYAPP folder in /Applications location contains a) myappmain.app b) logout.app

myappmain.app performs main function while logout.app is for logging off of user.

myappmain.app needs  support of two more apps for functioning named monitor.app and dialogbox.app.
Both monitor.app and dialogbox.app, I placed it in /Applications/MYAPP/myappmain.app/Contents/Resources location i.e. within main myappmain.app
All apps are written in python language.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the exact setup of your system and your app's structure, I can only offer general advice.

From what I gather, the basic procedure includes:
1) Set up a code signing identity (private key and digital certificate) either through the Apple Developer Portal or using Certificate Assistant under your Mac's Keychain Access. You can also use Keychain Access to import an existing certificate. You can also export certificates from Xcode.

2) Add an Info.plist file to your application bundle if it is a single-file tool.

3) Actually sign the code using the codesign command line tool from a terminal. You can then test the signatures you created with the spctl command line tool. I think you can also set up signing within the Xcode options.

I got this information from the following link. There are a lot more details here, and you may have to do extra steps depending on your system, but I hope this helps.
[Apple Developer Code Signing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/)

Comment: More details added. So I need to code sign  myappmain.app and logout.app and myapp.pkg. Can you elaborate the process

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have not been here for a while.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have not been here for a while.  Did you start by setting up an identity? After this, you should be able to open Terminal and use the codesign command referenced here: [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/codesign](OSX codesign man page)  i.e.: `codesign /path/to/mymainapp.app`    Again, the process may be simpler from within Xcode, if that's what you're using.